Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" while launching LibreOffice
I have some issues in ubuntu 24.04 with Libre Office (LibreOffice 24.8.3.2). It is opening very slow and is very laggy. In 22.04 it opened instantly.
I open the libreoffice from terminal:
:~$ libreoffice

(soffice:6537): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:49:34.093: GTK+ module /snap/libreoffice/334/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 11:49:34.093: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(soffice:6537): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:49:34.094: GTK+ module /snap/libreoffice/334/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 11:49:34.094: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"


I have installed the module "canberra-gtk-module" (even though he says it's not supported in GTK+ 3)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module

but the same problem when opening again....very slow and with the same warning.
Running stjournalctl -f and then open LibreOffice:
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine soffice.bin[4680]: GTK+ module /snap/libreoffice/334/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
                                               GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine soffice.bin[4680]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine soffice.bin[4680]: GTK+ module /snap/libreoffice/334/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
                                               GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine soffice.bin[4680]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.gnome.SessionManager" member="RegisterClient" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/libreoffice" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" name=":1.38" mask="receive" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2906 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.gnome.SessionManager" member="RegisterClient" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:36 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.gnome.SessionManager" member="RegisterClient" mask="send" name=":1.36" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2863 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:37 dev-machine kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1733392477.254:206): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.libreoffice.libreoffice pid=4680 comm="configmgrWriter" exe="/snap/libreoffice/334/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=92 compat=0 ip=0x7994716e1a6b code=0x50000
Dec 05 11:54:37 dev-machine gnome-character[4461]: JS LOG: Characters Application exiting
Dec 05 11:54:37 dev-machine dbus-daemon[2602]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/libreoffice" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" name=":1.38" mask="receive" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=2906 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec 05 11:54:37 dev-machine kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1733392477.945:207): pid=1216 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.Avahi" pid=4680 label="snap.libreoffice.libreoffice" peer_pid=1214 peer_label="unconfined"
                                     exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec 05 11:54:38 dev-machine kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1733392478.986:208): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.libreoffice.libreoffice pid=4680 comm="configmgrWriter" exe="/snap/libreoffice/334/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=92 compat=0 ip=0x7994716e1a6b code=0x50000


I have also tried to run libreoffice in safe mode:
libreoffice --safe-mode

it shows only 2 times the splash screen and close.
Anyone has this issue with Libre Office in Ubuntu 24.04 ?
